# Show off-topic reason while reviewing close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close, scope

When reviewing Close Votes in the review tools, it's always good to know for what reason it was voted for closure. The good news: It already does this!

However, it doesn't show the sub reasons of the off-topic reason. That means the only thing I can see when reviewing is that is was voted for being "off-topic". These reasons differ from belonging to another SE site to not providing enough information. It would be nice if this "subreason" is shown too, like:

> Should this question be closed as: **off-topic; This question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just click *(more)* to show the off-topic reason picked:

[image]

to expand to:

[image]

Comment: SO has so many hidden gems... Thanks for noting this one out!