# Failing the automatic review test - for no reason

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I'm sorry if this was asked before, but my search hasn't led me to the question I want to raise.

While reviewing (mainly, but not exclusively, close-votes) I sometimes fail even before I voted for closing the question. When I review I sometimes want to see why other people voted to close the question in order to understand why it got into the queue in the first place.

I understand that maybe the intention is for me to vote only according to my own opinion. But if that is so - why would I be able to see other people's votes in the first place?

This come as very annoying especially for the duplicate questions. It's very easy for me to go to the duplication voting screen and see the possible duplicates there instead of first see the duplicate and only then open the close window. In my way, if the question **is** a duplicate, I just vote for closing on the screen I'm already at.

I suggest accusing a user of not being careful enough with the review would happen only after the user finishes the review, and not before. Because when pressing to vote-close on a question, the user may still be allowed to regret.

Comment: You can see what people voted for by looking at the bar to the left of the buttons; it states there what people have voted for so far, albeit without vote counts. See [Show off-topic reason while reviewing close votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252358) as well.