# Expand off-topic reason in close queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, scope

It would be nice to see something along these lines:
[image]

Yes, I'm [aware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252358/show-off-topic-reason-while-reviewing-close-votes) that you can see the exact reason by clicking the `(more)` button. However, it would be nice to see the expanded reason without an extra click.

#### Use case

Some of the close reasons require minimal time to react appropriately. For instance,

- Questions seeking recommendations;
- Questions produced by an obvious typo and solved trivially in the comment section;
- Questions to be migrated to other site (e.g. to crossvalidated, typical for the R tag).

By adding an expanded close reason, we may further reduce the time required to vote in these rather obvious situations. It also will be possible to distinguish between a simple case (one of the above) and a more complicated one where a thorough reading of the question/comments is necessary to make a decision.

This experience may be biased by the specific of the tag I'm lurking in, but I don't think this feature will be harmful for any other user or tag.

#### Shortened off-topic reasons

These may look very minimalistic, for instance

- `looking for recommendation`
- `belongs to other site`
- `seeking debugging help`
- `not reproducible or typo`
- `custom reason`

The full description would be still available under the `(more)` section.

#### TL;DR

This is a time saver for the close queue that requires minimal implementation.

Comment: [MSE: Close Vote Review, additionally filter off-topic close reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191540/167646)

Comment: I don't think reducing the time reviewers take to come to a decision about review items is a goal that we should have. Pay less attention to other reviewers' opinions and focus on making the right decision about the content you're presented with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a very good idea and we should have it.

Actually I just came to MSO to ask for this specific feature myself and was pointed here by the ask-question dialog.

To me its frustrating to see a comment "oh I solved it; It was this typo..." after reading through the whole post. If I had the note that this question is to be closed because of a typo I would have checked the comments first.