# Can we make "off-topic" in the "Reopen Votes" review queue more specific?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I am reviewing posts which have been edited after they were closed in the "Reopen Votes" queue, I find a lot of the posts are flagged as "off-topic". Sometimes it is obvious as to why that is the case, but more often it's not, and it takes me longer (because I need to look in more depth at the question, comments and possibly even answers) to be able to decide whether I agree with the vote. I would like to propose that "off-topic" be sub-flagged with the reason (e.g. "off-topic: non-reproducible" or "off-topic: seeking recommendation" etc.) or that we get the information in the same manner as in the "Close Votes" queue as I think it would enable reviewers to focus more closely on the reasons already suggested for closing, potentially then speeding the process of reviewing the reopen vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show off-topic reason while reviewing close votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252358/show-off-topic-reason-while-reviewing-close-votes)

Comment: @StephenRauch have edited question to refer only to the "Reopen votes' queue.

Comment: In my opinion, this is still an issue. While some of the off-topic reasons are quite obvious, it is hard to distinguish "seeking help to debug" and "typo / hard to reproduce".